# How to form SAML request for SSO to another domain?

Tags: c#, angular, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have an angular application where it needs to SSO with a third party application when clicked on one of tabs. The third party has provided a SAML endpoint that I need to hit with a payload, and that will generate cookies for me and then I get hit other endpoints like the /authenticate and /token. I was using postman to make a post request with the payload but it is does not look like it is working. Any opensource or any nuget package C# I can use to send SAML request. How do I form my SAML response?

Comment: Did you choose any framework?

Answer (score 0):

At this point the best library to do this task is:

```
Sustainsys.Saml2
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sustainsys.Saml2/

https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/

https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2

1. Good documentation
2. Friendly testing environment
3. Easy to incorporate into your project
   I have used it in my project and it works well

Comment: Is there any sample application you know I can follow for doing this? I have a saml Assertion Url from a third app client that I need to hit with saml request parameters, trying to see how to form the request to hit the SamlAsserition url provided to get the cookies

Comment: This framework does it for you. You can see how it works from both sides 

here:https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/tree/master/Samples

There is a sample SAML id server (which can mock your third-party app) and a sample application that makes that call to that server.  But I must warn you SAML protocol isn't the simplest out there.